# angucomplete / angucomplete-alt: how to access api data

Tags: angularjs

I am beginning exploring angular.
I using angucomplete-alt to autocomplete a text box.

The API to which angular connects to populate the text box responds with a json object with also an 'id' field which I need to use in the form and which I obviously don't want to display.

The question is:  how can I access the 'id' field that without a second request beside the one made by angucomplete-alt?

Thanks very much in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set the callback function or $watch to selectedObject. When it gets called or triggered, you get the object from the json as selectedObject.originalObject. Inside originalObject, you should be able to find the id.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. At the moment I switched to JQuery, hope to find soon the time to test the solution. Thanks again